# docker-compose - Error: Cannot find module '/server/test-db'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run docker-compose up --build, the build process seems like successful.

But only container test-db is created successfully, while the container test-web_1 build failed and show below error message.

Error Message

```
test-web_1  | Error: Cannot find module '/server/test-db'
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /server

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3030

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  test-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET=1024M
      - MYSQL_INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE=1G
      - MYSQL_INNODB_LOG_FILE_SIZE=256M
      - MYSQL_INNODB_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE=256M
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  test-web:

    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=local
      #- DEBUG=*
      - PORT=3030
    image: node:lts-alpine
    build: ./
    command: >
       test-db npm run dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/server
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    depends_on:
      - test-db
```

Comment: In the `command:`, what does the word `test-db` mean?  Could you just `npm run dev` or the host using the Node you have installed there?